# AddPage function in django making a new page but not redirecting to it - NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, html, django, cs50

I'm trying to create a function that will make a new entry in a wikipedia website. So far the code I  have will make the entry (i.e. if you go through the form to make the page, it will show up in the list of pages on the home screen) but instead of bringing you to the page when you hit submit, it shows me a NoReverseMatch error. It's saying "reverse for 'entry' not found. 'entry' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

All I need it to do is redirect to the new page, but I can't figure out why it's saying entry isn't a valid view function? I have a function titled entry to hold the previous entries, but I'm having trouble connecting the issue.

VIEWS.PY

```
def entry(request, title):
    html_content = convert_md_to_html(title)
    if html_content == None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "message": "This entry does not exist."
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "title": title,
            "content": html_content
        }) 


class AddPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
        }))

def add_page(request):
    form = AddPageForm() # <- called at GET request
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPageForm(request.POST) # <- called at POST request
    
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        content = form.cleaned_data['content']
        entries = util.list_entries()
        for entry in entries:
            if title.upper() == entry.upper():
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        return redirect('entry', title=title) 
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/addpage.html", {
            "form": AddPageForm()
        })
```

URLS.PY

```
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("entry/<str:title>/", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search"),
    path("add_page", views.add_page, name="addpage"),
    path("edit_page/<str:title>", views.edit_page, name="editpage"),
    path("random_page/", views.random_page, name="random"),
]
```

ADDPAGE.HTML

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>New Page</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:addpage' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

UTIL.PY

```
def list_entries():
    """
    Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
    """
    _, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))
```

Comment: Have you tried with `encyclopedia:entry` instead of simply `entry` for your `redirect()` function call ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use reverse in your add page function for redirection.

sample code:

1. Import the reverse

   from django.urls import reverse
2. redirect using reverse url

   return redirect(reverse('entry', kwargs={'title':title}))

You can read more about reverse [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urlresolvers/)

Comment: No need to do that. See [redirect()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)